# Why my operator overloading not compiling?

Tags: c++

I have this member function

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream) const
```

in `Histogram<T>`.

then in another class I have

```
static void write(const RGBHistogram<T> &hist, Output &output)
{
    std::cout << hist.redHist << std::endl;
}
```

redHist, greenHist and blueHist are Histogram.

Why it complains that no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type Histogram?

Comment: It has to be a non-member function. `cout << hist` becomes `operator<<(cout, hist)`, which doesn't match your member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass referece of you class and it should be friend not member function.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &ostream, const RGBHistogram<T> &stream)
{

  // do something.
  return ostream;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Operator `<<` has to be implemented as a free function to be meaningful:

```
//inside class definition
//still free function
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const Histogram &) 
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can define it outside the class. (I prefer it like this since it groups together class functionality)

Comment: Shouldn't that take an `ostream&` as well?

Comment: It needs to be a `friend` only if the members to be accessed inside the function are `protected` or `private`.Also, it should also take `ostream &` as input parameter.

Comment: @Als declaring it as friend lets you implement it inside the class definition. That's what I meant.